# Where to put static files such as CSS in a spring-boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my current spring-boot project, my views have this line:

```
<link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

to reference a static css file. When I run the project, and access one of the views which reference this file, I get a 404 not found error or a 403 unauthorized error, depending where I put the file inside the project.

I try this so far:

```
src/main/resources/static/css (with this, I use css/signin.css instead of signin.css)

src/main/resources/templates/static/css (with this, I use css/signin.css instead of signin.css)

src/src/main/resources/templates/acesso (same folder of the html file)
```

what the right place to store this type of files?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Anywhere beneath `src/main/resources/static` is an appropriate place for static content such as CSS, JavaScript, and images. The static directory is served from `/`. For example, `src/main/resources/static/signin.css` will be served from `/signin.css` whereas `src/main/resources/static/css/signin.css` will be served from `/css/signin.css`.

The `src/main/resources/templates` folder is intended for view templates that will be turned into HTML by a templating engine such as Thymeleaf, Freemarker, or Velocity, etc. You shouldn't place static content in this directory.

Also make sure you haven't used `@EnableWebMvc` in your application as that will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC.

Comment: bad luck for me, none of the posted solutions here on SO worked for me :/

Comment: Is there any configuration which needs to be done to make spring boot use src/main/resources/static as the default location?  It's not picking up my css unless I load it from a CDN with a full url.

Comment: No, that's the default location. Just make sure you haven't used `@EnableWebMvc` in your application as that will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC.

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson, May I know how to handle the case when I have to use EnableWebMvc in my Spring Boot App.

Comment: Why would you have to use `@EnableWebMvc` rather than a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked perfectly for me. I had been looking for nearly an hour to figure this out! It would be really helpful to have a link or something showing where you found this information.

Comment: Thanks for this, Andy. I spent over an hour trying out various suggestions as to where to put Javascript files - static, WEB-INF, etc.. My Spring Boot application wouldn't load them. But deleting @EnableWebMVC from a Controller ENABLED loading from these folders as a side effect. Who'd have thought?

Comment: Removing @EnableWebMvc did the trick for me. I have been working on this one for hours! Wish I had seen this post earlier!!

Comment: It doesnt work for me... I have empty project with 1 controller with GetMapping("/")
and 1 template in template dir and static/css/style.css.
If i try to open it as with default browser - works. If i start Spring Boot and go to localhost:8080/ -  html without styles.

Comment: Removing `@EnableWebMvc` helped me too, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Apart from placing it anywhere beneath `src/main/resources/static` and not using `@EnableWebMvc`, you'll need to authorize access to your `js` or `css` folder especially if you have `spring-boot-security` in you classpath. You'll add something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MainSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me. But isn't this unsafe from a security POV?

Comment: @SwapnilIngle modify your antMatchers if you want certain resources to be secure.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But is it common/good practice to expose your js and/or CSS resources?

Answer (score 12):

You can use Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org/

Example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/signin.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to add xmlns and xmlns:th in your html tag.

Check your application.properties:

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
```

If that key is set to false, spring boot app will not load any resources.

Comment: This doesn't work as is. you got to put it in this folder.  <your project folder>/src/main/resources/static/css/signing.css

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 7):

I use Spring-Boot 2.0.2

I still keep `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in my `webConfig.java` and override `addResourceHandlers()` method to help browser reaches css and javascript files through http request.

This is the webapp directory's structure

[image: directory structure].

**webConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "example.com")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // =======================================
    // =             Bean Config             =
    // =======================================

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }


    // =======================================
    // =          Override Methods           =
    // =======================================

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdfs/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/");
    }
}
```

**index.jsp head tag:**

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: It might not help now.  Question was asked in 2014. Try to answer recent question. Will help you and me both....

Comment: @Ashish451 sorry if it is not the case, but if the answer is good and contributes, it isn't wrong answering old questions :). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/does-it-make-sense-to-answer-old-questions

Comment: Not working. try using this `registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/WEB-INF/");`

Answer (score 6):

Disabling `@EnableWebMvc` helped me to resolve issue.

Answer (score 4):

I use Spring-Boot with Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org/

This is the directory's structure like @[Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) Response

[image]

Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/w3.css" th:href="@{/css/w3.css}">
```

Comment: Simply as this sample, remove static keyword in the thymleaf declaration if you forgot.
This sample run perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I put my signin.css under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/static/css/signin.css, then I could access it using /css/signin.css

Not sure why though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case to reference files inside css and js folders like this:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I had to place the folders  in webapp folder.
I have the following folder structure:

Myapp

```
-src
     -main
           -java
           -resources
                    -static
                    -templates
           -webapp
                  -resources
                  -WEB-INF
```

I mean if i had placed the css and js folders in resources folder (under main) it would have been:

```
<link href="../resources/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If i place them in static folder (under resources) it doesn't work.

Comment: I that really working? I can't let it work with names like bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.min.js, while is working perfectly with names with no dots in basename, like somestyle.css or somescript.js. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722325/spring-serving-static-contents-with-dots-in-filename

Answer (score 1):

When i used:

```
src/main/resources/static/css.
```

my views have this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/signin.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- src/resource/static/css
- src/resource/static/js
- src/resource/static/images

Don't use `@EnableWebMvc` if you are using spring boot and check spring security.

Answer (score 0):

Put the required files inside static folder in spring boot. And then you can access the required files inside the jsp directly.

Hope it helps as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with the default spring boot initializer project structure the following works in intellij.

For clarity my html files reside here:

```
<src/main/resources/templates/html_files_here>
```

option 1 (when server is running)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

option 2 (when viewing html files without server running)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

In a Spring Boot project, you can organize your static files, such as CSS files, in the `src/main/resources/static` directory. This directory is automatically included in the classpath, and Spring Boot will serve the contents of this directory as static resources.

Here's an example directory structure:

```
src
|-- main
|   |-- java
|   |-- resources
|       |-- static
|           |-- css
|               |-- style.css
|-- ...
```

In this example, you can place your CSS file (`style.css`) inside the `src/main/resources/static/css` directory. When your Spring Boot application runs, the CSS file will be accessible at the path `/css/style.css` relative to your application's context root.

For example, if your application is running on `http://localhost:8080`, you can access the CSS file at `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`.

Remember that this is the default behavior, and you can customize it by modifying the application's configuration if needed. However, the standard approach is to use the `static` directory within the `resources` folder.