# Spring-Boot ResourceLocations not finding css file in resources/static/css

Tags: css, spring, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot project, when I do a maven build, my css stylesheet is not located.  I have already taken advice from the official Spring Boot documentation and other stackoverflow posts, and have put my css file in resources/static/css directory.

[image]

```
|_src
   |_main
   |_java
   |_resources
      |_templates
      |_static
         |_css
            |_master.css
```

Declaring the css stylesheet in the thymeleaf layout (html file under templates directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/master.css" th:href="@{/css/master.css}" media="screen"/>
</head>
```

My pom.xml includes spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, so it is expected that the Spring-Boot ResourceLocations should map static content to     src/main/resources/static.

I have also attempted:

```
th:href="@{css/master.css}"
```

AND

```
th:href="@{static/css/master.css}"
```

AND

```
th:href="@{../static/css/master.css}"
```

AND complete removal of th:href=...

Any ideas on what is preventing the stylesheet from being located?

Comment: This is the correct version `th:href="@{css/master.css}"` show me the rendered HTML output. Also try to access the css directly using http://localhost:8080/css/master.css

Comment: The templates and static should be stored under /WEB-INF instead of /resources. This resource could be helpful I think: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: I had tried storing the templates and statics under the different options that Spring Boot maps to including /WEB-INF.  After 5 days, it magically started working under the current directory structure, but I am unaware of what the issue was initially?  It could not have been a modification in code because the issue spanned over multiple separate projects, and then started working for all of them.

Comment: i slove my problem when <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> this code add spring-config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a correct project tree. This means that all **css**, **js**, **image** files must be in the **static** folder which also needs to be in the following folder **src/main/resources/**

Folder **static** is served from **/**. Something like that, **src/main/resources/static/master.css** will be served from **/master.css**

[More explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170772/where-place-static-css-file-in-a-spring-boot-project)

```
package com.lab;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 *
 * @author mdbah
 */

@EnableWebMvc 
@Configuration
public class Webconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");

    }
}
```

I also used this class to include bootstrap by webjars in my project, which prevented loading my css and js files from the static folder.
Because of this, I simply removed the **@EnableWebMvc annotation**, then recompiled the project. And now, voila

If you are in this context, this method regulates your concern

PS: Sorry, i'm not speak english well, hope you will understand something