# Spring serving static contents with dot(s) in filename

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to serve via Spring the web pages resulting from a build in npm and everything is working fine but I could not serve resources with name like main.xxxx.yyy no matter what the real suffix is (css, js or html).

the directory tree is like that:

```
src/main/resource/resource
                  index.html
                  asset-manifest.json
                  favicon.ico
                  manifest.json
                  service-worker.js
                  static
                     css
                         main.fc656101.css
                         main.fc656101.css.map
                     js
                         main.91794276.js
                         main.91794276.js.map
                     media
                         banner.bdcf92f4.jpg
                         fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d.svg
                         ...
```

This is the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   private static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/*").
                      addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }
        @Override
        public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
            super.configurePathMatch(configurer);

            configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

To debug the issue I've manually renamed some files and it works, so I've restricted the problem to the file names having dot(s) in it.

I've saw that someone has solved a similar problem adding {variable:.+} in request mapping in RestControllers, but I don't have controllers, so I could not figure out how to do it.

EDIT:

I've found that with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(final PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

}
```

Now it serves all *.html, included page.01.html, but still not style.01.css or script.01.js. I assume is a different problem and the original one is solved by ContentNegotiationConfigurer.

Comment: Why is this tagged npm? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with node.js.

Comment: Becouse the static contents with dots in filenames is produced by npm run build command.

Comment: I don't think that is relevant for your problem, as I would assume the same would happen if you create those files manually, right? And if not, that is an important thing to mention explicitly.

Comment: No, is not important per se, in sense that the problem raise up no matter how you produce the file names with dots in it, but I think is important becouse  exlplains why changing names is a no-go,  so it prevent solution like "why  don't you simply change filenames?" or similar.

Comment: Then you should mention that explicitly, however tags themselves should be specific to the problem/question, and not enumerate all 'related' technologies.

Comment: I'm too lazy to test it right now, but shouldn't you be using `addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**")`? That is, `**` to indicate 'including resources in nested folders'.

Comment: yes, and it does not works. More, it seems to me is not necessary, resources with proper names are loaded also without adding that line.

Comment: BTW, I've removed the npm tag.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this should be a very stupid question...

Problem was browser cache and project cleaning. Be sure to ALWAYS clear the cache (that's quite obvious) but also clean the project from where you serve the static contents after changing configuration. Stop and restart JAVA is not enought.

That costed to me three days but now is working, and the correct configuration is the first I've posted, no needs for contentNegotiation configuration.

Hope this could save a day for others!