# Failed to load resource css file. Freemarker

Tags: java, html, css, spring, freemarker

@English isn't my first language.

I use freemaker in my spring project. But I can't link css file.

[Here tree and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BG4W.png)

Error : 
GET http://localhost:8080/static/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 login:6

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"/>` isn't wrong..

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M15eR.png)

```
<#macro page>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"/>
<#--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<#nested>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

Comment: your first error is to link to code and an error message, instead of pasting those in your question.

Comment: @clevercat Please, copy or type the code and error text into the question - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Watch image 1 at line 6. (what we could see at image 2). Where is the problem? Code fine.

Comment: The template is valid, check under what resource your CSS is accessible, then fix the url in your template.

Comment: check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170772/where-to-put-static-files-such-as-css-in-a-spring-boot-project#answer-27173104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you configured the `/src/main/resources/static` directory to serve the files?

If you using Spring Boot and its default configuration, then `static` isn't part of the URL path, so you should be using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
```

Comment: I didn't change any configurations. Search what's wrong soooooo long..
How I could change this configurations?

Comment: Omfg just didn't change any think and now it works.. Set path like you write. Thank you and soorapadman for help!